Movie about a time-traveling guy from the middle ages
This movie is about a guy who brings back some people from the middle age (might be his direct ancestors).
This middle age people are a leader (a lord maybe), and his companion (slave).
This lord always feed bones to his slave.
He also ate a toilet freshener from a urinal.
Finally this lord got back to his time, but his slave stays in the present time, riding in a car with his lover as I remember.

You probably mean Les visiteurs with Jean Reno from 1993 (or its remake Just Visiting from 2001):

A medieval nobleman and his squire are accidentally transported to contemporary times by a senile sorcerer. He enlists the aid of his descendent to try to find a way to return home, all the while trying to cope with the cultural and technological changes distinguishing his time from ours. 

From another synopsis:

Despite the utterly predictable development and conclusion, there are a few choice scenes where centuries clash. One involves the travellers bathing delicately out of a toilet bowl. Another involves Andre eating off the floor of a posh restaurant while Thibault magnanimously tosses him scraps of T-bone eaten with his hands while their hosts look on aghast. The scene ends with Andre innocently offering his social betters bits of urinal cake as after-dinner mints.

Actually, this is very probably the 2001 remake (which also stars Reno) because it ends in the manner you've described. There was also a 1998 sequel to the original film. Here's the trailer of Just Visiting:



